# Proving a loop that performs n^2n by induction

Tags: induction

I have a function computes n^(2n) and I need to prove by it by induction. Here it is in python:

```
def n_to_2n(n):
    product = 1
    counter = n
    while counter > 0:
        product = product * n * n
        counter -= 1
    return product
```

I believe I've found a useful loop invariant: `product = n^(2*(n - counter))`. For initialization and termination, this LI is trivial to prove, but I'm having difficulty proving the maintenance stage by induction. There's two variables, so which one do I perform induction on? I tried on n but didn't get anywhere really.

Assume LI(n) holds, prove LI(n + 1): ???

Comment: I believe you should use the fact that result is n^(a_n) at any n and prove by induction only the fact that a_n=2n.

Comment: Prove that for all $i$ such that $0 \leq i \leq n$, after the $i$th iteration of the `while` loop, `counter` is $n - i$ and `product` is $n^{2i}$.